# Gulp: How to compile multiple .pug files into several index.html files inside folders

Tags: gulp, pug

I'm learning to use gulp and I decided to use `pug` for writing all my html.

The thing is that have this folder structure:

```sh
src/pug
├── base
│   ├── mixins.pug
│   └── variables.pug
├── components
│   ├── footer.pug
│   ├── header.pug
│   ├── head.pug
│   └── template.pug
├── index.pug
└── views
    └── about.pug
```

And I want gulp to ignore all files that are not index.html and all my files inside the views folder.

I'm doing that using this configuration:

```js
function compilePug() {
  return src(['./src/pug/index.pug','./src/pug/views/*.pug'], {base: './src/pug/'})
  .pipe(pug().on("error", console.log))
  .pipe(
    pug({
      // Your options in here.
    })
  )
  .pipe(dest('./dist/'));
};
```

The thing is, that's creating and output like this `dist/views/about.html`.

But I rather generate something like this `dist/about/index.html`.That way I can navigate between multiple pages without having a route with the `.html` extension at the end.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've written an npm module that does this: [`gulp-url-builder`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-url-builder).

First, move your `index.pug` into your `views` directory. Everything you want to render as a page should go in there. Don't forget to adjust any `extends` path to your template.

```
src/pug
├── base
│   ├── mixins.pug
│   └── variables.pug
├── components
│   ├── footer.pug
│   ├── header.pug
│   ├── head.pug
│   └── template.pug
└── views
    ├── about.pug
    └── index.pug
```

After you've installed in required the url builder module in your gulpfile, you can modify your `compilePug()` function to look something like this:

```
const { src, dest, series, parallel, watch } = require('gulp')
const pug = require('gulp-pug')
const urlBuilder = require('gulp-url-builder')

function compilePug() {
  return src([
    './src/pug/views/*.pug'
  ]).pipe( pug() )
    .pipe( urlBuilder() )
    .pipe( dest('dist') )
}
```

This will output html files based on this pattern (note that underscores can be used for nested pages):

```
src/pug/views/index.pug        --> dist/index.html
src/pug/views/about.pug        --> dist/about/index.html
src/pug/views/foo-bar.pug      --> dist/foo-bar/index.html
src/pug/views/blog.pug         --> dist/blog/index.html
src/pug/views/blog_my-post.pug --> dist/blog/my-post/index.html
```

Comment: Thank you so much Sean. I really appreciate how good your answer is. I mean, is an absolutely fantastic solution that worked perfectly for me.